# Replicate Gmail user+something@gmail.com functionality using Postfix

Tags: postfix

With gmail it's possible to put a + after your username followed by an identifier. See [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/1-awesome-gmail-tip-you-dont-know-about-seriously/) for an example. Is it possible to replicate this functionality with Postfix? We have a postfix/spamassasin/clamav relay in front of our Microsoft Exchange server, and it would be useful to add this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just set [`recipient_delimiter`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_delimiter) in `main.cf`.

```
recipient_delimiter = +
```

It probably is already set.

Comment: This works if postfix is delivering the mail locally, however if it is relaying on then the +xxx gets included so gets rejected by the Exchange server.

Comment: You should probably ask about how to support the functionality in Exchange, then.

Comment: point well made ;) i'll close and open a new question