# Replicate Gmail user+something@gmail.com functionality using Exchange 2010 and/or Postfix

Tags: email, postfix, exchange-2010

With gmail it's possible to put a + after your username followed by an identifier. See [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/1-awesome-gmail-tip-you-dont-know-about-seriously/) for an example. Is it possible to replicate this functionality with Exchange?

We have a postfix/spamassasin/clamav relay in front of our Microsoft Exchange server if it helps, as [I know](https://serverfault.com/questions/487589/replicate-gmail-usersomethinggmail-com-functionality-using-postfix) you can use the `recipient_delimeter` setting there to achieve this but I don't see how to pass that on to Exchange.

Comment: This link might be useful on a general basis: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_addresses#Address_tags

Answer (score 1):

I can't promise that this will work properly, since I'm not all too familiar with Exchange, but it might be worth giving a shot.

First, you enable the `recipient_delimiter` setting in your postfix server.

Second, you have either a rewrite map, or a .forward in the users home directory, that will rewrite the recipient back to the "real" mail address, and deliver it to the exchange server.

This should have the following effect:

- An email arrives to the postfix server. Both the envelope recipient and the "To: " header should be recipient-extension@yourdomain.com.
- Postfix rewrites the **envelope recipient** to recipient@yourdomain.com, but will leave the "To:"-header unchanged
- The mail gets delivered to the exchange server, and since the envelope recipient now is the same as the email address that Exchange knows about, Exchange will deliver it to the user.
- The user can filter based on the "To:"-header.

This last part will obviously not work when the mail is sent e.g. to a mailinglist, since they often keep the mailing list as the To:-header in the mail. You might have postfix/procmail insert a header with e.g. "Originally-To" in the mail, if exchange/Outlook/whatever client they're using can sort on that.

Answer (score 0):

if you can get spam assassin or postfix to insert a header with the folder name then you could create an  inbox rule in outlook or PowerShell that runs based on that header.